# How to configure webform with smtp

Tags: 7, webforms

I have create a webform and i want to configure it sending emails with smtp authentication. I have install the SMTP authentication module also, but i cant find any option that allows me to setup webform for using smtp.

Is this possible? Any advice?

Answer (score 11):

Webform module uses the `mail()` for sending the mails. `SMTP Authentication Support` module allows Drupal to bypass the PHP `mail()` function and send email directly to an SMTP server.

Along with `SMTP Authentication Support` module you would need to install the [Mail system module](https://drupal.org/project/mailsystem) and configure it to assign a smtp class to webform which is  step by step explained in this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20131027093924/http://blog.celoxgroup.com.au/drupal-7-webform-doesnt-send-emails-smtp-gateway-out).

If you have [SMTP module](https://drupal.org/project/smtp) installed in your drupal site than you would have to configure the SMTP settings (`/admin/config/system/smtp`) for sending the email

Example (Configuring SMTP for GMAIL):

```
A. INSTALL OPTIONS:
 1. Turn this module on or off: (SELECT "ON")

B. SMTP SERVER SETTINGS:
 1. Server: smtp.gmail.com
 2. Backup server: (LEAVE BLANK)
 3. Port: 465
 4. Use encrypted protocol: (SELECT "Use SSL")

C. SMTP AUTHENTICATION:
 1. Username: (ENTER YOUR GMAIL EMAIL ID)
 2. Password: (ENTER YOUR ABOVE EMAIL ID PASSWORD)

D. E-MAIL OPTIONS:
 1. E-mail from address: (ENTER YOUR GMAIL EMAIL ID AS ENTERED ABOVE)
 2. E-mail from name: (ENTER SITE NAME, ITS DEFAULT VALUE IS DRUPAL VERION)
 3. Allow to send e-mails formated as Html (ENABLE CHECKBOX IF YOU WANT)

E. SEND TEST E-MAIL:
 1. E-mail address to send a test e-mail to: 
   (ENTER YOUR EMAIL ID AT WHICH YOU WANT TO RECEIVE TEST MAIL)
```

Instead of GMAIL if you want to use some other service provider than check their [server details](http://serversmtp.com/en/what-is-my-smtp) and the [port details](http://serversmtp.com/en/port-for-smtp).

Comment: @drupspark Has the above solution worked for you, or if you found some better solution than please share. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible.The Problem is that by default webform send emails out via mail(). To fix it we have to assign a smtp class to webform. To do so follow [this](http://blog.celoxgroup.com.au/drupal-7-webform-doesnt-send-emails-smtp-gateway-out) step  and in order to configure smtp with a gmail account @Ankit has mentioned it very clear here already.

steps in summary

- You need to settup [mailsystem](https://drupal.org/project/mailsystem) : this module will help us
  configure mail variables or we can see it will tell webform to use
  smtp.
- As given in step guide select webform in thee new setting, keep the key as empty save the settings and now you see "Webform module
  class" select-list on the top of same page where you have just saved
  the settings.
- Here is the "Webform module class" select-list you can set the webform to use smtp module.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal [SMTP auth module](https://drupal.org/project/smtp) can help you.

**SMTP Auth:**

> This module allows Drupal to bypass the PHP mail() function and send email directly to an SMTP server. The module supports SMTP authentication and can even connect to servers using SSL if supported by PHP. This module uses the smtp and mail class's from PHPMailer. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Although this may answer the question, link-only answers are discouraged. Could you please expand and explain how the OP can use this module with a webform.

Answer (score 1):

This are the steps you have to follow to configure Mail System Module on Drupal 7

Step 1: Go to Configuration > System > Mail System
Step 2: Go to new setting
Step 3: Select the mail system you want to use with the module

[image: Step 1: Go to Configuration > System > Mail System]

[image: Step 2: Go to new setting]

[image: Step 3: Select the mail system you want to use with the module]

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that only two projects support SMTP authentication?
https://www.drupal.org/project/phpmailer
https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp
Both still in beta.
Typical mail server today won't send any mail without smtp authentication (not talking about VPS or spam services).