# SMTP settings not being used

Tags: emails

I've been working on a existing drupal site I got from a client, and have been running into some problems when I try to change the smtp settings. The SMTP module was already installed, but when I change the settings in SMTP Authentication Support and send a test mail, it works, but it still keeps using settings from somewhere else (I presume). I've checked the config files for settings, but I can't seem to find anything. All cache has been turned off. I'm not an expert on drupal by any means, so is there some other place I should be looking or do I need to change some other settings?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the answer to [How to configure webform with smtp](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87087) , which includes:

> If you have [SMTP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) installed in your drupal site than you would have to configure the SMTP settings (/admin/config/system/smtp) for sending the email ...

It also includes an example for configuring SMTP.